# Generating a list of substrings not in a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of strings and a list of substrings. I want to generate a list of substrings not in the list of strings.

```
substring_list=["100", "101", "102", "104", "105"]
string_list=["101 foo", "102 bar", "103 baz", "104 lorem"]
```

I tried to do `new_list = [s for s in substring_list if s not in [i for i in string_list]]`, but this doesn't work. I've also tried various uses of `any()` but have had no luck.

I'd like to return `new_list=["100", "105"]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
[sub for sub in substring_list if all(sub not in s for s in string_list)]
# ['100', '105']
```

---

Or alternatively:

```
[sub for sub in substring_list if not any(sub in s for s in string_list)]
# ['100', '105']
```

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: Why would be the second method any more efficient?

Comment: And `all` stops the iteration whenever it encounters a false, but `any` has to keep going until it encounters a true. I'd say `all not` and `not any` are perfectly equivalent, whatever the input data is.

Comment: @EricDuminil Ahh I guess you are right. I think it wrongly.

Answer (score 1):

Coming from a Ruby background and since Python has `any` and `all`, I looked for a [`none`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-none-3F) function or method but was surprised to see it doesn't exist.

If you often use `not any` or `all not`, it could be interesting to define `none()` :

```
def none(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return False
    return True

substring_list = ["100", "101", "102", "104", "105"]
string_list = ["101 foo", "102 bar", "103 baz", "104 lorem"]

print([sub for sub in substring_list if none(sub in s for s in string_list)])
# ['100', '105']
```

It might lead to confusion with [`None`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.NoneType) though. That's probably the reason why it doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

Code written returns all because "for i in string_list" creates a new set identical string_list array solve it is split handy split the organs to benefit string_list and then when you start i [0] you create similar string_list system but contains only numbers without letters

**so**

```
new_list = [s for s in substring_list if s not in [i.split()[0] for i in string_list]]
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.